# Is it only possible when 600J of heat is exhausted and 400J of heat is converted into work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

[image: Ques]

Is it only possible when 600J of heat is exhausted and 400J of heat is converted into work? Is the 600J heat will enter the cold reservoir and available to do work again?

q1/T hot + q3 / T cold = 0

q3 = 600 when T = 300K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carnot efficiency = 1 - Tc/Th = 1 - 300/500 = 0.4

The carnot efficiency is the maximum efficiency allowed by any thermodynamic cycle.

In your example, the efficiency of 0.5 exceeds the maximum allowed hence it is not thermodynamically possible.